# What does "Average Position" mean in Google Webmaster Tools under Top pages?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

What does "Average Position" mean in Google  Webmaster Tools under Top pages?
I can only find the definition for "Average Position" under Search Queries.

Answer (score 1):

It means essentially the same thing- of all the searches that resulted in an impression *for the page* (verses search term as in your example), an average position of all of the SERP positions is displayed. I know that sounds the same as average search query position but it is not. One is searches by term and an impression regardless of the page, and the other is page regardless of the search term.